# Why Pycharm doesn't find system Python libraries?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new in Python and I have this sample code to test some libraries (I've installed all needed libraries with `pip`).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

myarray = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
plt.plot(myarray)
plt.xlabel('some x axis')
plt.ylabel('some y axis')
plt.show()
```

when I run the code from command line (macOS) via command `python main.py` I get chart as expected. Bud when I run the same code in Pycharm I get an error related to missing libraries.

> /Users/jirka/PycharmProjects/sandbox/venv/bin/python
> /Users/jirka/PycharmProjects/sandbox/main.py Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File "/Users/jirka/PycharmProjects/sandbox/main.py",
> line 2, in 
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Q: What I have to set in Pycharm to find installed system libraries?

Edit: I just add to the accepted answer that the Python interpreter can be in Pycharm set globally for all projects.

[image]

Comment: There's `/venv/bin/python` in your path which means that you're using virtual environment for your project. Virtual environment is an independent *(almost)* copy of python, so you need to install your requirements for this virtual environment. You can check [Install, uninstall, and upgrade packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

Comment: If you don't want to use virtual environment, you can choose another interpreter.

Comment: OK, I will check Pycharm preferences again.

Comment: @bad_coder Not exactly, thanks, but Alexis's answer does.

Comment: @Artegon FYI the linked duplicate target includes the answer by Alexis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try file -> Settings -> Project : xxxx -> Python Interpreter
Then change Python interpreter from venv to your local python.exe